# Running cmd from absolute path has it fail to recognise manage-bde command

Tags: windows, cmd, autoit, bitlocker

I'm trying to use cmd.exe through AutoIt script. When I `run(c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe)` and try to launch `manage-bde` the error

> is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

is coming. `run(cmd.exe)`, `manage-bde` works well. With the complete path included, I wonder why first command doesn't work.

Additionally, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and run `cmd.exe`, then launch `manage-bde` works well. Windows and search `cmd.exe` and launch `manage-bde` works as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some files in `System32` are not in `SysWOW64`.

On a 64 bit OS running a 32 bit process, redirection sets the system folder as `SysWOW64`.
You can access the `System32` folder by using the magical `SysNative` in the path i.e.

```
C:\Windows\SysNative\cmd.exe
```

or from this help page [Running under Windows 64-bit Edition](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3//docs/intro/64-bit_support.htm) you could use (*and use False argument when done*)

```
_WinAPI_Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(True)
```

or run AutoIt as 64 bit.

Comment: @user10057923 Select this answer if it helped.